# Recovering from stream.Read() exception

Tags: c#

I have a function to request an update from the server. I provide the query and also indicate the expected length of the response.

```
public Byte[] GetUpdate(Byte[] query, int expLength)
{
    var response = new Byte[expLength];
    lock(Client)
    {
        Stream s = Client.GetStream();
        s.Write(query, 0, query.Length);

        var totalBytesRead = 0;
        var numAttempts = 0;

        while(totalBytesRead < expLength && numAttempts < MAX_RETRIES)
        {
            numAttempts++;
            int bytes;
            try
            {
                bytes = s.Read(response, totalBytesRead, expLength);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new IOException();    
            }
            totalBytesRead += bytes;
        }
        if(totalBytesRead < expLength)
        {
            // should probably throw something here
            throw new IOException();
        }
    }
    return response;
}
```

The function that calls the above function is given below. Both of them belong to `class Connection`.

```
public Byte[] GetData(string ip, int port ,Byte [] query, int responseLen)
{            
    Connection connection = GetConnection(ip,port);
    Byte[] data = null;
    try
    {
        data = connection.GetUpdate(query, responseLen);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        connection?.Disconnect();
        return new Byte[0];
    }
    return data;
}
```

My question is as follows.

With the above code I am trying to read some values of a remote network endpoint. Sometimes the connections go down on the link. I test the scenario by manually unplugging the Ethernet cable. Once I unplug and plug the cable I sometimes find that `s.Read()` in function `GetUpdate` throws `StreamReadFailed` exception.It happens occasionally. What could be the possible reason for this and what is the best way to recover from this.?

Comment: What exception does it throw? What is `Client`? `Client.GetStream()` can be related to this question.

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev - `StreamReadFailed` exception